# Why do I run out of disk space when I attempt to update a VirtualBox VM to Windows 10?

Tags: windows-7, macos, windows-10, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I have installed VirtualBox (version 5.22 with latest guest additions) on MacBook Pro (running Yosemite) and have one VM which is running Windows 7.

I want to upgrade this to Windows 10. The Windows 10 upgrade guide says that I need 8GB of disk space on the VM. My VM has 12 GB of free space. My Mac host has 40GB of disk space free.

When I try to run the update I notice that when it reaches 20%-21% percent, the host runs out of disk space, the VM aborts and I am not able to start it.

Why is this happening? How do I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have read it wrong. According to Microsoft Windows 10 requires at least 15 GB free space to be installed.

You can see this in the error message.

Increase the VM storage to at least 20 GB and then try again.

Comment: I created some space by getting rid of old update files etc... and was able to install, it gave me a warning about not having the correct drivers for VirtualBox graphics adapter, which I ignore. Now when I try to install guest additions the VM aborts.